# How to set collectionsjs equals and compare?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, collections, compare

I want to use http://www.collectionsjs.com/sorted-map data structure. In the factory method it has the option to define equals and compare: `SortedMap(entries, equals, compare)`.

What would be the formats of these two parameters?

I would guess they are functions receiving two items and returning a boolean?

(please also provide suggestions and hints even if you don't know the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I faced with a lack of documentation and tutorials regarding SortedSet too.

You can create function-objects (callbacks) and pass them to the constructor of the Data Structure.

### Equal

Specifies a function that implements the deep-equal comparison of entities, useful if you have unusual data structures, like Vec3(x, y, z).
In this case, your equal function will look something like:

```
function(left, right) {
   return left.x === right.x && left.y === right.y && left.z === right.z
}
```

### Compare

Specifies a function that defines the sort order of your entities in the Data Structure.
Similarly to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax)
Something like:

```
function(left, right) {
    return left.x < right.x ? 1: -1
}
```